# C# Syntax Error Near Table Name

Tags: c#, sql, database, select

I am having some problem when trying to check login credential for 3-tier project in C#.

Currently, I have a table named User with userName and password columns.

In my BusinessLogicLayer, I get the user input and pass them to dataAccessLayer:

```
public string checkCredential(string userName, string password)
{
    string returnMessage = "";
    User user = new User(userName, password);
    Boolean success = user.checkCredential();
    if (!success)
    {
        returnMessage += "Username and password does not match!";
    }
    else
    {
        returnMessage = "";
    }
    return returnMessage;
}
```

In my Data Access Layer, I got a method to check for login creddential:

```
public Boolean checkCredential()
{
    Boolean result = false;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FFTHDb.connectionString)) // get your connection string from the other class here
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT userName, password FROM User WHERE userName = '" + userName + "' AND password = '" + password + "'", connection);
        connection.Open();
        using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And I got a separated class to set the connection string:

```
public static string connectionString = DataAccessLayer.Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnStr;


public static SqlDataReader executeReader(string query)
{
    SqlDataReader result = null;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FFTHDb executeReader: " + query);

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();
    result = command.ExecuteReader();
    connection.Close();

    return result;
}
```

There is no compilation errors. And I double checked for the table name and columns in database. However, it just keeps telling me that there is syntax error near User. I wonder why is it so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`User` is a [*reserved keyword*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) on T-SQL. You should use it with square brackets like `[User]`

Also using *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)* always a good practice.

And **Never store passwords in plain text!** Use [SHA-512 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

Answer (score 0):

User is a reserved keyword so you need to add square brackets around it. For a list see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).
So, you should do it like this

```
SELECT userName, password FROM [User] WHERE userName =
```

Answer (score -2):

**Problem :** the table name which you have provided is `User` is a Keyword in `Transact-SQL`.
  [Reserved Words](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

**Solution:** Enclose the reserved word `User` in square brackets `[]`.

**Solution 1:**

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT userName, password FROM [User] WHERE userName = '" + userName + "' AND password = '" + password + "'", connection);
```

**Solution 2:**

```
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT userName, password FROM [User] WHERE userName= @username AND password = @password", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",userName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",password);
```

Comment: It works. But why do we need to add the square bracket?

Comment: Explain your answers.

Comment: I kind of get it already. Is it true that we always needed to surround table name with [] in asp.net?

Comment: @Downvoter would be glad if you could improve this.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: pleae check my explanantion.

Comment: @Gwen: no need to always keep table names in square brackets , but you should enclose them if it is a reserved word.