# Error in creating in table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to create table through c#
I am using following code

```
private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionstring = "server=.;database=Student;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        string fee_table = @"
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'fees') AND   type in (N'U')) CREATE TABLE user (user_name char(50),password char(50));";

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(fee_table, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

but iam getting runtime error syntax error near user

Comment: Hi, What error are you getting?

Comment: The first Google result for "ms-sql syntax error near user" is [this SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543395/c-sharp-syntax-error-near-table-name), which is closed as a duplicate of [Creating table names that are reserved words/keywords in MS SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695578/creating-table-names-that-are-reserved-words-keywords-in-ms-sql-server). Please try to search first.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'user1'.

Comment: @user3809448: I doubt this. Can you copy this query in sql and see if there is any error?

Comment: it is running sucessfully without[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). Change it to `[user]`.

[image]

Change to

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`user` is a keyword in many databases. You either need to change the name of the table or quote it. For example, in SQL Server do this:

```
CREATE TABLE [user] (user_name char(50),password char(50))
```

In other database systems you may be able to use:

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (user_name char(50),password char(50))
```

Or:

```
CREATE TABLE 'user' (user_name char(50),password char(50))
```

Comment: i chnged the name of table but still same error

Comment: Same error? I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

`USER` is a *[`reserved keyword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)* in T-SQL. You should use it with squared brackets `[]`. However, the best solution is to change the name to a nonreserved word.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

```
string connectionstring = "server=.;database=Student;Integrated Security=True";
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring ))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
     ...
     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: if i change the table name then also i will have to put [] in table name